# Conditional formatting in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Hi I want use conditional formatting. On this values:

[image]

everything works, but when i change values (mid and max values are similiar) to:

[image]

conditional Formatting do not works. What I do bad?

Comment: what is the values of `C8` and `C7`?

Comment: C7 is 4, C8 is 2.

Comment: check your calculation mode: _Formulas --> Caluculation options_ and also try to press F9

Comment: No change (calculation options = auto).

Comment: I find what is wrong - C7 & C9 not contain value. They contain equation, like that "=B10". Is there a possibility to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the referenced cell contains valid numbers.

To check this, put the formula `=Mechanic!$C$8` in a blank cell. I.e., make sure C8 in worksheet named Mechanic contains 2 and C7 contains 4.

If they do contain the correct values then make sure they are formatted as number and not text. If these two are taken care of you should be good to go.

Comment: These cells contained string. When I multiplied cells by 1, conditional formatting works. Thanks!